# Using typescript with vue 3 without using the vue cli

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We're looking into an existing web project that uses vue for enriching the pages generated by an aspnet core project. The client side is already written in Javascript 6+ (using modules, etc) and the idea is to see if it's possible rewrite it in typescript.

Since the demo code is already written in Javascript 6+, updating it to typescript shouldn't be that hard, but I'm not sure on how to add type information when you're using the options api and you're not using vue components and the its cli.

For instance, how do I get the correct type of a property from the object returned from the data method?

Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Options api isn't good enough with TS, this is one of reasons why composition api appeared

Comment: So, in order to use it with typescript, do you recommend migrating to the composition api? Can it be done with the options api? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely recommend that. You don't have to use Vue CLI specifically but I expect TS to work best with Vue SFC. You can use it with options api you'll run into numerous limitations because it wasn't designed for TS. Vue class components were TS-oriented but they are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

To use typescript in Vue Options API you should wrap your Options components into [defineComponent](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent)

```
export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({...}),
  props: ['a', 'b'],
  computed: {...},
  // template: '...'
});
```

---

However, that won't work with templates, if you don't use tooling to use `.vue` files (as templates are just strings, while in vue files they are seperate language)

If you want to switch to tooling, check out the latest Vue `script setup`

(I was rewriting .vue in Options into Script Setup, with some hand-made regex-based converter making half of work)

Maybe some component framework like https://quasar.dev/

Maybe with plugins like `unplugin-auto-import` (removes need in importing often-used things like `ref` of `computed`)

Comment: Hello. I've found that method on the docs, but I've noticed that I still have no intellisense on VS Code (ex.: on a component's method, accessing this.X where X is a prop or a data object property returns any) ...

Comment: try a clean example, `let a = defineComponent({
  data: () => ({a: 1}),
  props: ['b'],
  computed: {
    d() {  return this.a  }
  },
  methods: {
    m() {
      return this.a + this.d
    }
  }
})`

Comment: Not sure how it works with mixins, but basic things work ok for me